# Seeking Recommendations for Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) Tools for CSV Data Analysis

Tags: data-cleaning, large-language-model, huggingface

After spending significant time on data engineering tasks, I'm looking for RAG tools or similar technologies that support CSV files. My project involves extracting information on specific conditions from over 10 years of hospital data in CSV format. Most tools I've found cater to PDFs. Does anyone know of any tools that could streamline this process for large CSV datasets?

I plan to prepare the CSV first, then use RAG to extract some data regarding some specific conditions. Then I will re-organize the output from RAG to CSV again. (I am also not sure if this is a good idea, so please correct me if I'm wrong)

I have tried RAG from Hugging Face, but it seems that it can work on PDF only (correct me if I'm wrong please). can anyone suggest some RAG for CSV files, so I can reduce my work on data engineering?